# Oracle cursor with IF inside, help needed

Tags: oracle, cursor

I am struggling with a cursor, tried different version with no luck and decided to ask for help here. How to make the IF condition work? I have to count something and then check if this count is greater than 10 and then delete something. How to pass the count(*) to IF condition and then do something? Thanks in advance.

```
 DECLARE
  CURSOR MY_CURSOR
      IS

SELECT CSH.STATUSCHANGEDDATE AS STATUSCHANGEDDATE_, CSH.CUSTOMER AS CUSTOMER_ from        CUSTOMER_STATUSES csh WHERE 
csh.STATUSCHANGEDATE>SOME_DATE AND CSH.STATUS = 'X_STATUS'


 MY_RECORD MY_CURSOR%ROWTYPE;

    BEGIN
      OPEN MY_CURSOR;
      LOOP
        FETCH MY_CURSOR INTO MY_RECORD;
        EXIT
      WHEN MY_CURSOR%NOTFOUND;


SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE SOME_DATE = STATUSCHANGEDDATE_ AND ....

    iF ABOVE_COUNT = 10 THEN
        DELETE * FROM SOME_TABLE2 WHERE SOME_CONDITION2
  ELSE 
 END IF

      END LOOP;
END LOOP;
 COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

In declare:

```
COUNT_VAR NUMBER(38);
```

In body:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO COUNT_VAR
FROM SOME_TABLE 
WHERE SOME_DATE = STATUSCHANGEDDATE_ AND ....;

IF COUNT_VAR = 10 THEN
    DELETE * FROM SOME_TABLE2 WHERE SOME_CONDITION2;
END IF;
```